# Active directory + public DNS

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, active-directory

I have a Windows Server 2008 installed on a machine at a co-lo facility. I made it a domain controller for Active Directory, and it also runs DNS.

On the machine if I ping one of the hosted A entries - for example foo.example.com - it works fine. If I use `netstat -a`, it shows me the server listening on port 53 (UDP and TCP). The DNS Manager properties for the server shows "Listen on all IP addresses". I also disabled the firewall for all profiles temporarily just to check. So it should just work, right?

Using DNSStuff to look up the DNS entries I get an error - the DNS server isn't responding. If I ping the domain from an external machine, it does not resolve the name. A web-based port scanner says that port 53 is not responding (I assume it means TCP).

Here is a snippet from the netstat output:

```
TCP    10.0.0.50:53           OptimusPrime:0         LISTENING
TCP    66.240.234.144:53      OptimusPrime:0         LISTENING
UDP    10.0.0.50:53           *:*                    
UDP    66.240.234.144:53      *:*
```

There are no relevant entries in the event log as far as I can see. Other services (such as VPN) on the machine accessed via that same IP address work fine.

Does this suggest a routing issue or perhaps the co-lo facility doing some filtering? What should my next step be in diagnosing this issue?

Comment: "on the machine if i ping [..] it works fine", but "i ping the domain locally [..] it does not resolve" can you clarify? sounds like the same thing, but contradictory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can do nslookup internally but not externally, and you don't have a firewall setup, my guess would be the location has some sort of hardware firewall active.

Answer (score 1):

If you can hit the service locally (on the server), but not from a remote location (from the server), that sounds an awful lot like the co-lo is either not permitting DNS requests into the box or not permitting DNS responses out. Unless you have another server local to the DNS server in question, your next step would be to talk to the co-lo.